# How to support thread-confinment with dynamic proxies?

Tags: java, multithreading, proxy

In Java Concurrency In Practice Brain Goetz adives us to support thread-confinment through "dynamic proxies". He said:

```
[...] provide a proxy object that intercepts calls to thread-confined object and submits them as tasks to the dedicated thread.
```

That's pretty clear. We just wrap our class in some proxy-class which does the job. But further he added (emphasize mine):

> If the class to be thread-confined implements an interface, you can
>   automate the process of having each method submit a Callable to a
>   background thread executor and waiting for the result using ***dynamic
>   proxies***.

It's not clear. Can you provide some practically-useful example of this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html

Comment: @JBNizet May I ask you a question? Have you used such techinque in production ever? To me it seems as a little bit complicated one... maybe because of lack of experience.

Comment: No, I have rarely created dynamic proxies myself, and never to achieve thread confinement. But Dynamic proxies are used all the time (for different reasons) in frameworks like Spring. The huge advantage over proxies coded by hand is that you can use the same dynamic proxy delegate to work with any number of interfaces you want, instead of having to create a new proxy by hand for each new interface that must be proxied.